# How to run my Django project on Apache server on exampp server?

Tags: django, apache

I'm in localhost after running Apache and MySQL ; Xampp give me a Server Erorr(500) . in apache erorr.log there is a error . it is :
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'digionline'\r, referer: http://localhost/

my code in httpd.conf:

LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/hameds510/appdata/local/programs/python/python37/lib/sitepackages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win_amd64.pyd"

WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Users/Hamed-S510/Desktop/hamed/digionline/wsgi.py"

WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/hamed-s510/appdata/local/programs/python/python37"

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the answer was right infront of me.
I hope your Django project name is digionline - so the wsgi.py script will be placed inside digionline/digionline/.
Therefore try, `WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Users/Hamed-S510/Desktop/hamed/digionline/digionline/wsgi.py"` instead of `WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Users/Hamed-S510/Desktop/hamed/digionline/wsgi.py"`